# Golang Module Use

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to link to some code online: https://github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait

I am helping out with this project and have altered that repository to create a new package called audiofilelibrary.

I am then trying to use that code in a very simple program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait/audiofilelibrary"
    "github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait/playlist"
)

func main() {

    audio := audioFileLibrary.AudioFileLibrary{}
    fmt.Println(audio.soundsDirectory)
    sched := playlist.Schedule{}
    fmt.Println(sched.Description)

}
```

You'll see I'm importing 2 packages from that repository, audiofilelibrary and playlist.  playlist works, audiofilelibrary does not.  They seem to be coded in the same way.

This is the error I get:

```
$ go build
go: finding github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait v2.0.0
go: finding github.com/nathan-osman/go-sunrise latest
go: finding github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait/audiofilelibrary latest
build audiobaitpackagetest: cannot load 
github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait/audiofilelibrary: 
cannot find module providing package 
github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait/audiofilelibrary
```

And this is my go.mod file, which is in a directory called audiobaitpackagetest:

```
module audiobaitpackagetest

go 1.13

require github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait v0.0.0-20191013210352-81b0afd9a085
```

I created the module with the command `go mod init audiobaitpackagetest`.

How can I see the audiofilelibrary package please? As in, how can I import it into other code?

The code for this question is all here, so it can be easily cloned and run: https://github.com/Davo36/audiobaitpackagetest

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using version [v2.0.0](https://github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait/tree/v2.0.0) of `github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait`.

This version doesn't contain `audiofilelibrary` package. But the `master` branch contains it.

You can change your `go.mod` file like this to use the `master` branch.

```
module audiobaitpackagetest

go 1.13

require github.com/TheCacophonyProject/audiobait master
```

Then run this commands:

```sh
go mod tidy
go mod vendor # if you want to vendor it
```